# R using ifelse to change factor values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a column that's a factor variable.  I need to change the value of all cells where the factor is a certain rarely occurring level.  I'm using the following code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
test2$timeFactor <- ifelse(test2$timeFactor == '94', '-1000', test2$timeFactor)
```

I've also tried:

```
test2$timeFactor <- factor(ifelse(test2$timeFactor == '94', '-1000', test2$timeFactor))
```

but neither seems to work.  Anything obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are better off changing the `levels`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- factor(sample(letters[1:3],10,replace=T))
x
 [1] a b b c a c c b b a
Levels: a b c

levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="c")] <- "z"
x
 [1] a b b z a z z b b a
Levels: a b z
```

Comment: The following syntax offers more flexibility: `levels(x) <- list(a="a", b="b", z="c")`, but it can be tedious if there are a lot of levels.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
test2 <- transform(test2,  timeFactor = ifelse(timeFactor == '94', '-1000', timeFactor) )
```