# Changing elements of a factor vector based on logical conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, logic, na

Is there a convenient and universal way to change elements of a factor vector (containing various factor levels and missing values as elements) based on logical conditions (in this case: for a subset of the vector, change missing values to a factor level) in R?

Given the factor vector (`fact`) and the logical vector (`sel`) produced here:

```
fact0 <- c("no","no","maybe",NA,"yes","yes","no","no",NA,NA,"maybe") 
fact <- factor(fact0) 
sel <- c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
```

And the desired output:

```
 [1] no    no    maybe no    yes   yes   no    no    no    <NA>  maybe
Levels: maybe no yes
```

My first idea was to use `ifelse()`, but that seems to convert the factor vector to "character" or "numeric", like this:

```
ifelse(is.na(fact) & sel, "no", fact)
ifelse(is.na(fact) & sel, 2, fact)
```

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194454/r-using-ifelse-to-change-factor-values) gave an interesting answer based on `levels()`, but that solution was not able to deal with missing values as a part of the logical conditions:

```
levels(fact)[which(is.na(fact) & sel)] #Output is "[1] NA NA"
levels(fact)[which(is.na(fact) & sel)] <- "no"
levels(fact)[which(is.na(fact) & sel)] #Still "[1] NA NA"
```

An ugly solution would be to change the factor vector to "character", do `ifelse()` on that, and convert back to a factor, like this:

```
char <- as.character(fact)
char2 <- ifelse(is.na(char) & sel, "no", char)
fact2 <- factor(char2)
fact2 #This is the desired output
```

Is there a more elegant method without this conversion trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option that just iterates through the "fact0" vector and replaces any NA values with "no" where the same index in "sel" is TRUE

```
sapply(seq_along(fact0), function(i) as.factor(ifelse(sel[i] & is.na(fact0[i]), "no", fact0[i])))
 [1] no    no    maybe no    yes   yes   no    no    no    <NA>  maybe
Levels: no maybe yes
```

Comment: That produces a character vector, though. I guess it would be a one-liner if you enclosed it in ´factor()´. Is it possible to change the relevant elements without converting to "character"?

Comment: Oh I see the concern is just the extra step(s) between converting b/w character and factor. Wrapping your original solution in as.factor would do the trick as well: as.factor(ifelse(is.na(fact0) & sel, "no", char))

Comment: Yeah, but thanks for the effort. Will accept your answer after some time if no one comes up with a better answer. Please edit it with an enclosing factor(), though.